# GCC require move ctor for awaitable object, even if it's lvalue

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, coroutine

When calling `co_await request(xxx)` in a coroutine the GCC compiler asked for move ctor even if the `request` function returned lvalue reference. Is this a bug? Seems this behavior is not compliant with the standard. Checked with clang and it compiles.

simple code snippets:

```cpp
#include <coroutine>

using namespace std;

struct awaitable {
    awaitable() = default;
    awaitable(const awaitable&) = delete;
    awaitable(const awaitable&&) = delete;

    bool await_ready() { return false; }
    void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> h) { }
    void await_resume() {}
};

awaitable& request();

struct task{
  struct promise_type {
    task get_return_object() { return {}; }
    suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };
};
 
task test_coroutine() {
  co_await request();
}
```

compile with `g++-11 -c -std=c++20 test.cxx` gives

```
test.cxx: In function ‘task test_coroutine()’:
test.cxx:28:22: error: use of deleted function ‘awaitable::awaitable(const awaitable&&)’
   28 |     co_await request();
      |                      ^
test.cxx:8:5: note: declared here
    8 |     awaitable(const awaitable&&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: "co_await suspends a coroutine and returns control to the caller. Its operand is an expression whose type must either define operator co_await, or be convertible to such type by means of the current coroutine's Promise::await_transform" - seems, the reference gets stripped somehow.